# Make a path for create a file in Java (Android)

Tags: java, android

Given a File object how can I create the path for saving it?

I tried file.mkdirs() but for example if the file's path is:

```
/mnt/sdcard/downloads/myapp/temp/song.mp3
```

it also creates a folder named "song.mp3" inside temp.

How can I do it correctly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this code

```
File myDir=new File("/sdcard/Download");
myDir.mkdirs();
String fname = "Image.jpg";
File file = new File (myDir,fname);
```

Answer (score 3):

Just try:

```
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
```

this will create the parent directory.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understand correctly what you need is

[File.getParent()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getParent%28%29)

hope it helps

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to extract the path you can use `lastIndexOf`:

```
String p = "/mnt/sdcard/downloads/myapp/temp/song.mp3";
System.out.println(p.substring(0,p.lastIndexOf('/')));
```

Of course, if you already have `File` object then `getParent()`, as suggested, will be easier.