# How to create files and folders in  SD card in Samsung Galaxy S II

Tags: android

how to create file and folder in to SD card  in samusun galexy S2 provide me code..or any prormistion to giving that i give this permition

Comment: see my answer for this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7818901/make-a-path-for-create-a-file-in-java-android/7818938#7818938

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
File newDir = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/newDirectory");
newDir.mkdirs();
```

and in manifest.xml file give permission

```
"android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
```

Comment: this all i done in other device that work not in samusung gelexy

Comment: just check external storage of samsung galaxy, If your program run fines without error then its created directory. just path of external storage is changed.

Comment: @user370305 As far as I understand `getExternalStorageDirectory()` will create `newDirectory` in user preferred storage (which is generally internal memory). so, what happens if the default storage has been set to `External memory` and it's not **readable/writable**? Does this throw exception? or it will automatically create in `Internal storage`?

Answer (score 0):

This article explains how to access to external storage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

With

```
 Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString();
```

you obtain the path to sdcard